# How to suppress exceptions from yfinance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf

try:
    data = yf.download(tickers=all_symbols[:50], start=start, end=end, group_by="ticker")
except:
    pass
```

Seems like that should hide all exceptions thrown by yfinance, but when a ticker name isn't found, I always get exceptions cluttering up my Jupyter notebook. how do i get them to stop appearing?

```
Exception in thread Thread-333:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/__init__.py", line 313, in history
    quotes = self._parse_quotes(data["chart"]["result"][0])
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/__init__.py", line 162, in _parse_quotes
    timestamps = data["timestamp"]
KeyError: 'timestamp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/__init__.py", line 470, in _download_one_threaded
    period, interval, prepost, proxy)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/__init__.py", line 483, in _download_one
    proxy=proxy)
  File "/Users/jason/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/__init__.py", line 316, in history
    raise ValueError(self.ticker, err_msg)
ValueError: ('ACCP', 'No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted')
```

Comment: None of these exception messages refer to the line of code that you gave at the top.  Are you sure that's how you are calling it?

Comment: @JohnGordon That is the cell in my jupyter notebook. that's all that's in the cell. I run the cell, it'll run through the first 50 symbols, and if any can't be found by the yfinance package, I'll get those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exceptions are in separate threads, which is why you are not catching and suppressing them.  It's also why the remaining results continue to download properly.

Your primary issue is that you have bad data, and fixing that bad data will solve your problem.  ACCP has not had it's IPO yet, it may never as its been in the works for at least 3 years.

You have a few options:

- Find a more accurate source of stock symbols to use.
- Run with threads=False or one at a time, which would stop when it hits an error, then remove the bad symbol and continue on.  That would slow the process down as it is not multithreaded.
- Ignore the errors the first run, then look through the data for what is missing, then remove those symbols for future runs.
- Edit your local yfinance to handle the exception in _download_one_threaded and suppress the error.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the multi-thread issue. Weeks later I still had not identified that being the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Can you work with this?

```
# https://towardsdatascience.com/efficient-frontier-portfolio-optimisation-in-python-e7844051e7f
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import quandl
import scipy.optimize
np.random.seed(777)


quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'you_resy_goes_here'
stocks = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT', 'SBUX']
data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = stocks,
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['date', 'ticker', 'adj_close'] },
                        date = { 'gte': '2018-1-1', 'lte': '2019-12-31' }, paginate=True)
data.head()

data.info()

df = data.set_index('date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
for c in table.columns.values:
    plt.plot(table.index, table[c], lw=3, alpha=0.8,label=c)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('price in $')


returns = table.pct_change()
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
for c in returns.columns.values:
    plt.plot(returns.index, returns[c], lw=3, alpha=0.8,label=c)
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('daily returns')


###################################################


def portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix):
    returns = np.sum(mean_returns*weights ) *252
    std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    return std, returns

def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios))
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(4)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record


returns = table.pct_change()
mean_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
num_portfolios = 25000
risk_free_rate = 0.0178


###################################################


def display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate):
    results, weights = random_portfolios(num_portfolios,mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate)

    max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
    sdp, rp = results[0,max_sharpe_idx], results[1,max_sharpe_idx]
    max_sharpe_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[max_sharpe_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    max_sharpe_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in max_sharpe_allocation.allocation]
    max_sharpe_allocation = max_sharpe_allocation.T

    min_vol_idx = np.argmin(results[0])
    sdp_min, rp_min = results[0,min_vol_idx], results[1,min_vol_idx]
    min_vol_allocation = pd.DataFrame(weights[min_vol_idx],index=table.columns,columns=['allocation'])
    min_vol_allocation.allocation = [round(i*100,2)for i in min_vol_allocation.allocation]
    min_vol_allocation = min_vol_allocation.T

    print("-")
    print("Maximum Sharpe Ratio Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp,2))
    print("\n")
    print(max_sharpe_allocation)
    print("-")
    print("Minimum Volatility Portfolio Allocation\n")
    print("Annualised Return:", round(rp_min,2))
    print("Annualised Volatility:", round(sdp_min,2))
    print("\n")
    print(min_vol_allocation)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.scatter(results[0,:],results[1,:],c=results[2,:],cmap='YlGnBu', marker='o', s=10, alpha=0.3)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.scatter(sdp,rp,marker='*',color='r',s=500, label='Maximum Sharpe ratio')
    plt.scatter(sdp_min,rp_min,marker='*',color='g',s=500, label='Minimum volatility')
    plt.title('Simulated Portfolio Optimization based on Efficient Frontier')
    plt.xlabel('annualised volatility')
    plt.ylabel('annualised returns')
    plt.legend(labelspacing=0.8)


display_simulated_ef_with_random(mean_returns, cov_matrix, num_portfolios, risk_free_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed in 0.1.46. Errors are printed after all the downloads complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering an issue with yfinance and would appreciate guidance on how to handle exceptions effectively. To locate the yfinance module on my system, I executed the following:

```
import yfinance as yf
file_path = yf.__file__
print(f"The yfinance module is located at: {file_path}")
```

After finding the location, I navigated to the multi.py file and located the download function. In this function, I introduced a variable in my local version called downloading_error=True, modifying the function signature like so:

```
def download(tickers, start=None, end=None, actions=False, threads=True, ignore_tz=None,
         group_by='column', auto_adjust=False, back_adjust=False, repair=False, keepna=False,
         progress=True, period="max", show_errors=None, interval="1d", prepost=False,
         proxy=None, rounding=False, timeout=10, session=None, downloading_error=True):
```

To suppress the error, I added a conditional statement:

```
if downloading_error:
    if shared._ERRORS:
        #...
```

This modification effectively handles exceptions during the download process. If downloading_error is set to True, it logs errors and tracebacks, providing a clearer overview of the issues encountered during the download.

```
data = yf.download(symbol, start="2022-01-01", end="2023-01-01", downloading_error=False)
```

In this code snippet, when calling yf.download, downloading_error=False is explicitly passed as an argument. This ensures that the downloading_error parameter is set to False during the data download for each symbol, suppressing the detailed error logging behavior introduced in the modified download function. This approach allows for more controlled error handling based on your requirements.